# Id not being identified in MainActivity.cs

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio Xamarin to develop an Android app, using AXML and C#. I had previously made the app in another project, but accidentally, I renamed some files and it went haywire. So i decided to make a new solution and copy the code in it. I just Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V'ed the AXML code, and copied the C# code carefully line by line. Now the problem is that the C# code is unable to get the buttons component by its ID. I have 2 EditTexts, 1 TextView and 5 buttons in my AXML, each with a different Id. here's a part of the AXML code-

```
<TextView
        android:text="Result"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/outputText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="ADD"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:onClick="addclicked" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
    <Button
        android:text="SUBTRACT"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSub" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
```

And here's a part of the C# code

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace SimpleCalculator.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "SimpleCalculator", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public TextView outputText;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            Button btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);
            Button btnSub = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSub);
            Button btnMul = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnMul);
            Button btnDiv = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDiv);
            Button btnClr = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnClr);
```

I'm getting an error in every line where I used the command FindViewById. The error is-

> Resource.Id does not contain a definition for "The ID I used for the control"
>   Please help.

Comment: Resolved. I don't know why, but when I closed the project and restarted my pc, all errors gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by closing Visual Studio and restarting my PC.